# Multiple Keylisteners Java

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, jpopupmenu

currently im trying to code a grid based game.
ive already managed to implement a key listener for general navigation. 
but when pressing a certain key, a Jpopup Menu opens.

now i want to implement navigation for the menu aswell with a key listener. Pressing B is supposed to close the menu again.

```
  KeyListener  UnitActionMenuKeyListener =   new KeyListener()          { 
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) 
    {

    if (evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_B)

        menu.setVisible(false)
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu("UnitActionMenu");
    JMenuItem bewegenItem = menu.add("test");
```

Using menu.show and menu.addKeyListener after this.

But no matter what i try, either my general navigation wont work anymore, or the general navigation will work, but my menu wont react to pressing B

so, how do i implement multiple key listeners for multiple elements?
i just want my main window to listen (and react) to some key differently than my menu

(sorry for bad writing, my english isnt that good and im frustrated by failing a simple task for more than 4 hours)

Answer (score 2):

Swing key bindings are generally better than key listeners. Key listeners have issues related to the focus system. That's what the problem you're having sounds like. When the popup is active, it steals the focus. Only the focused component will send out key events.

There's a tutorial for key bindings here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

The API is a little more complicated but they're more robust and you can specify the focus behavior directly.

---

Here's a quick guide for converting key listeners to key bindings.

For a key listener, you have some code that's like this:

```
myComponent.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    ...
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Z)
            performZAction();
    }
});
```

Writing a key binding would be like this:

```
KeyStroke keystroke =
    KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("typed Z");
myComponent.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)
    .put(keystroke, "zAction");
myComponent.getActionMap()
    .put("zAction", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            performZAction();
        }
    });
```

In other words, there are three steps:

1. Creating a [`javax.swing.KeyStroke`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html) object with `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke`.
2. Using the input map, bind the keystroke to a name for your action.
3. Using the action map, bind the name for your action to a `javax.swing.Action`.

The `Action` is your listener. You can extend `javax.swing.AbstractAction` and it's just like writing an `ActionListener`.

Comment: sadly i dont understand how keybindings work. the examples given are pretty complicated. 
the menu i want to use is in focus and predefined keybinding (like naviganting with arrow key) are working. my own key binding/listeners (quitting with B) doesnt work